# How to Convert MYSQL Query to Mongodb Aggregation

Tags: mysql, mongodb

how to convert mysql query to mongodb aggregation

my database in mysql

[image]

i need to convert mysql to mongodb query

```
SELECT * FROM `auctions` WHERE ( (status!='SCHEDULED' AND status='FAILED') OR (status!='RUNNING' AND status='FAILED') ) GROUP BY auctioncode
```

in this query auctioncode and status are wise record needed auctioncode is multiple records. i need status='FAILED' that auctioncode status not in **SCHEDULED** or `UNPAID`

Comment: You convert the mysql query to mongodb aggregations manually, by hand.  The MongoDB BI Connector will translate a SQL query to MQL but it is not originally intended for this purpose, and gathering the MQL will not be an easy task.

Comment: Would be helpful if you can provide sample data, expected output and your current trial in MongoDB for everyone else here to have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below can be done pls refer here for example query: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8zHYhXvbkxs

```
db.auctions.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "$and": [
            {
              status: {
                $ne: "SCHEDULED"
              }
            },
            {
              status: "FAILED"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "$and": [
            {
              status: {
                $ne: "RUNNING"
              }
            },
            {
              status: "FAILED"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$auctioncode",
      "auctioncode": {
        "$first": "$auctioncode"
      },
      "Details": {
        "$addToSet": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Pipeline stages:
match: to filter based on your requirement!
group: to do group by auctioncode

Comment: I Have a another status also check 'UNPAID' how to code. I changed   status: "UNPAID" both side but result not came

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/D3cAnirlA41 refer this i want 'UNPAID' also @Programmer Analyst

Comment: i think you need UNPAID and FAILED... pls refer to https://mongoplayground.net/p/frOTNhTKziL